# &quot; instead sign of quote (")

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding, sign, quote

I have writteln asp.net web projet in C#.

The problem is in saving sign of quote `"` in a database and displaying this again in a page.

For example there is a textbox and I type following:

```
"abcd"
```

and save this in DB.

However, when I read this again and display it in a page I see:

```
&quot;abcd&quot;
```

So what is a problem here?Does someone know the solution?

the charset I use is utf8 and colattion is utf8generalci

Comment: How to you save it to the DB, how do you read it ? This is not an encoding issue, but a html conversion somewhere.

Comment: What is in the database? What code do you use to display it?

Comment: @spender in database table I see &quote instead of "

Answer (score 2):

Try use HTML decode and encode

HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332854%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is actually desired behavior - `&amp;quot;` is the escaped html entity `"`. It's a security issue  to output literal " as it can enable Cross-Site-Scripting or Cross-Site-Request-Forgery.

// sorry, please note freefaller's correct answer below.

Comment: No it isn't... `&amp;quot;` is the escaped version of `&quot;`, which is the escaped version of `"`.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say - formatting messed that up. You are correct, of course.