# C# String.Format replaces escaped quotes into &quot;

Tags: c#, string, format, escaping, quotes

I'm trying to format a String using the String.Format function, but my double quotes keep getting replaced by the HTML safe version of this (`&quot;`).
Needless to say this is not the result I would expect.

My current code looks like this

```
string String= String.Format("{0}: {{ name: \"{1}\"}}", node.Category, node.Name);
// Output ==> SomeCategory: { name: &quot;SomeName&quot; }
```

I've tried replacing the `&quot;` by actual quotes in the output, but that also didn't work.Is there some voodoo I can use to fix this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show a little code around this because the problem is not caused by the `format` call.

Comment: This String is put in a List<String> which is passed using Razor's ViewBag. In the view, I iterate through the List and display the strings.

Comment: Try using the `@Html.Raw( ... )` helper to display the string.

Comment: @Willem As commented under your answer,  I am currently using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not caused by `String.Format()`, more likely it is caused by whatever you use to view the data, or by something that happens before you view the data.

Judging from your format string it looks like you're trying to create a JSON string to return (possibly from a service). There is a big chance something will HTML encode your string on it's way to the client. The problem lays there, not in your string formatting, and thus trying to fix it there will not work.

Comment: That would explain a lot (as I couldn't find this particular problem in any other StackOverflow issue and the format function shouldn't replace special characters).

The problem lays in what you already suggested, the view. Razor's display will automatically encode the HTML. Using the Html.Raw() function disables this and doesn't replace the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use HTML decode and encode
That way you can turn them in actual quotes.

HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332854%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Stackoverflow source: [&quot; instead sign of quote (")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473534/quot-instead-sign-of-quote)

Comment: If replacing the `&quot;` does not work, this will not work either.